# Consul for Docker container discovery: how to get latest container in Consul-Template?

Tags: docker, load-balancing, service-discovery, consul, consul-template

I'm building out a Docker host where I'd like to do a no-downtime upgrade of a running container. For now, assume I'm only running one container.

I build a new image and launch a container from it with `docker run -P ...`, so that it is assigned random host ports. Then I can use something like [Registrator](http://gliderlabs.com/registrator/latest/) to automatically update a service in Consul. Now, Consul has two registrations for the service corresponding to the image name: the old container and the new container.

I'd like to update my nginx reverse proxy configuration to point to the new container's port using [Consul-Template (as described here)](http://www.luiselizondo.net/a-production-ready-docker-workflow-part-4-service-discovery-and-the-load-balancer/). **How do I make Consul-Template only fetch the details of the newest container?**

Two solutions I have considered are:

- Using the `CreateIndex` to find the newest registration for this service. Not sure how to make Consul-Template sort by CreateIndex, however.
- Using service tags. **The issue is that I'm not sure how to remove tags from previous containers/Consul service registrations**. If that were possible, then I could just assign a particular tag to the new container(s) and [select them in Consul-Template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/issues/33). This would scale to doing no-downtime upgrades of multiple containers.

**Update:** I've found some documentation on how to update/clear tags: [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/consul-tool/mmIWeqnDAX8), [2](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/867), [3](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/1048). This could be done on old containers that are running before new containers are started with the tag.

Is this the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could consider integrating service discovery into your applications operation. Either run a consul agent within your container or get your container to register its service on startup. This enables you to specify additional health checks on the service that enable consul to detect when the service is switched off or becomes unavailable. See: https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html and https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/external.html

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks for the pointer -- I'm new to Consul and am grateful to hear about these features.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem of getting oldest/newest instances in Consul Template recently. I couldn't find any hints on the Internet, so I'll leave the answer here.

The only attribute I found in Consul that allows to differentiate age of instances is CreateIndex. It would be easy to use it in Consul Template:

```
{{- $newest_backend := "" }}
{{- $create_index := "0" | parseUint }}
{{- range $c,$d:=service $name -}}
    {{- if gt $d.CreateIndex $create_index }}
        {{- $newest_backend = (print "oldest_instance " $c " " $d.Address ":" $d.Port) }}
        {{- $create_index = $d.CreateIndex}}
    {{- end}}
{{- end}}
{{ $newest_backend }}
```

but unfortunately, the HealthService struct that the service function returns, doesn't get this attribute from Consul. I had to [extend it](https://github.com/thabiger/consul-template-builder/blob/main/patches/0001-Adds-CreateIndex-attribute-to-the-HealthService-stru.patch) to make this example work properly.